Validating signatures signed with Safe app
I'm investigating how to make the "Sign-in With Ethereum" library work with Safe signatures. First, I signed the message below using the Safe app on Base Sepolia:
<domain> wants you to sign in with your Ethereum account:\n<address>\n\nPlease sign in to verify your ownership of this wallet\n\nURI: h<domain>\nVersion: 1\nChain ID: 84532\nNonce: <nonce>\nIssued At: 2024-10-10T08:34:03.152Z\nExpiration Time: 2024-10-13T08:34:03.249112Z

The message is in the format required by Sign-in With Ethereum. Then I used the isValidSignature function in protocol-kit to validate it like the following:
async function validateSafeSignature(
  rpcEndpoint: string,
  safeAddress: string,
  message: string,
  signature: string
): Promise<boolean> {
  const protocolKit = await Safe.init({
    provider: rpcEndpoint,
    safeAddress
  });

  const messageHash = hashSafeMessage(message);
  console.log(messageHash);

  const isValid = await protocolKit.isValidSignature(messageHash, signature);
  console.log(isValid);
  return isValid;
}

validateSafeSignature(
  'https://sepolia.base.org',
  '<address>',
  '<message>',
  '0x'
);

But the function returns false even though I've signed the message in the Safe app. I've also checked that the messageHash matches the one displayed in the app when I signed it. I did notice that the actual message I signed in Metamask is a hash displayed under the "SafeMessage" section in the app, but I tried to pass the hash in to isValidSignature and it's not working either. Any idea why it's not validating? I feel like I might be missing something basic here.
Thanks!
-------Edit-------
Ah I figured out, it's because by default the messages are stored off-chain. I changed the settings to store messages on chain and now it's working.

Ah I figured out, it's because by default the messages are stored off-chain. I changed the settings to store messages on chain and now it's working.

Hey, hmmm, great, you figured it out yourself! You could also use the ApiKit (https://docs.safe.global/reference-sdk-api-kit/getmessage) or the API to receive messages that are stored off-chain if you want to safe on gas.
